# Tikz : astronomy

Tags: tikz-pgf, metapost

How can I translate this [Metapost source] to Tikz?

```
for i:=0 upto 12:
        yy := 50 - (25 / 3 * i);
        xx := - sqrt(3600 - yy * yy) - 10;
        drawarrow (-100,yy)--(xx,yy) withcolor (1,1,0);
    endfor;

    fill fullcircle scaled 100 withcolor (1,1,.3);
    fill (halfcircle--cycle) rotated -90 scaled 100 withcolor (.3,.2,.1);

    draw axe rotated 23;

    for i:=1 upto 7:
        yy  := 50 - i * 12.5;
        xx  := sqrt(2500 - yy * yy);
        draw ((xx,yy)--(-xx,yy)) rotated 23 withpen pencircle scaled .5pt
        withcolor .6white;
    endfor;

    label.urt(btex $N$ etex,(0,50) rotated 23);
    label.lrt(btex $S$ etex,(0,-50) rotated 23);
```

This is what the output is supposed to look like:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! This is English speaking site ... Please can explain what is your problem,, the best in form an MWE (Minimal Working Example),, which reproduce your problem,

Comment: At the very least you could tell us how the figure should look like. It seems to be a metapost file but not everyone knows how to compile it, which modules need to be loaded and so on.

Comment: Why do you want to redo the code in Ti*k*Z? That seems to be a pointless task since you have the code in MetaPost. Ti*k*Z has no native support for `pen`s of the kind MetaPost has. (There's a package for calligraphy, but it is nowhere near as generally usable.)

Comment: You are missing the definition of `axe`.  You wan't to add something like `path axe; axe = (down--up) scaled 52;`

Answer (score 4):

Here is an idea.  It is not perfect, since I'm not use to the MetaPost syntax. But I think it is a good starting point. If anyone see a way to improve this code, I'm open to suggestion.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

% define your color, same syntax as xcolor package
\definecolor{mysunray}{rgb}{1,1,0}
\definecolor{myday}{rgb}{1,1,0.3}
\definecolor{mynight}{rgb}{0.3,0.2,0.1}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1pt,y=1pt]
% the sun rays
\foreach \x in {0,1,...,12}
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\yy}{50-25/3*\x}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xx}{-sqrt(3600-\yy*\yy)-10}
\draw[->,>=latex,mysunray,line width=1pt] (-100,\yy) -- (\xx,\yy);}

% earth
\fill[myday] (0,-50) arc (270:90:50) -- cycle;
\fill[mynight] (0,-50) arc (-90:90:50) -- cycle;

% parallels
\foreach \x in {1,2,...,7}
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\yy}{50-\x*12.5}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xx}{sqrt(2500-\yy*\yy)}
\draw[black!40,line width=0.5pt,rotate=23.43] (-\xx,\yy) -- (\xx,\yy);}

% earth axis and poles
\node (north) at (90+23.43:60) {$N$};
\node (south) at (-90+23.43:60) {$S$};
\draw (north) -- (south);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This code give
[image]

To define the color, I use the option `rgb` which use number between 0 and 1.  There is also the option `RGB` which take integer between 0 and 255.

For the color of the parallel, I used `black!40` which is 40% black (and 60% white).  I'm not sure if it is the same as your `0.6white`.